# Javascript/c# fullcalendar Print events titles+descriptions

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

is there a way to print event descriptions in javascript/c# fullcalendar as well as the title?
Im using

```
<style type="text/css">
            @media print { 
            .visible-print {
                
            }

            .hidden-print {
                display: none !important;                
                 }
        }
            
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
            $('.printBtn').on('click', function () {
                window.print();
            });
</script>
```

and the Html:

```html
  

  <button class="printBtn hidden-print" style ="background-color: #28a745;color :white;border-radius: 2px;border:none;width :75px;height:35px; ">
```

Comment: What version of fullCalendar? Have you already rendered the descriptions onto the event (using the custom functionality available for that) - even if you made it so they are hidden in non-print mode (if that's what you require)? CSS cannot show what is not already there, it is not able to pull data from the fullCalendar event data held in JavaScript, it can only rearrange the html and content which is already available.

Comment: P.s. this has nothing to with c# as far as I can see, even if your application has a c# backend, it has no control over printing in the browser. You can remove that tag I think.